# Performance of C++ containers during thread execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, c++14

I am working on a project that uses multiple threads to parallelize tasks. During development, I noticed that performance of operations on a std::list container, e.g. pop_front() or push_back(), are significantly slower while executed in the thread, compared to single-thread execution. See the code snipped below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

void SingleThreadedList()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
    {
        list<char> l;

        for(int j=0; j<10000; j++)
        {
            l.push_back('c');
            l.pop_front();
        }
    }

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "duration single thread: " <<  duration << endl;
}

void MultiThreadedList()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto lambda_fkt = []() {

        list<char> l;

        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            l.push_back('c');
            l.pop_front();
        }
    };

    vector<thread*> thread_array;
    for (int i=0; i<2; ++i)
    {
        thread *th = new thread(lambda_fkt);
        thread_array.push_back(th);
    }

    for(auto t : thread_array)
    {
        t->join();
    }

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    std::cout << "duration multi thread: " <<  duration << endl;

    for(auto t : thread_array)
    {
        delete t;
    }
}

int main() {
    SingleThreadedList();
    MultiThreadedList();
}
```

the code produces the following output:

```
duration single thread: 4589
duration multi thread: 245483
```

Single Thread variant takes 4 ms, but as soon as the threads are created, execution takes more than 200ms! I cannot imagine that standard library containers show such a performance difference, depending on the execution context. Therefore I wonder if maybe someone can explain to me, what happens in this code and how I can avoid the performance decrease within `thread`? Thank you!

PS: When I remove the list operations from this sample and add e.g. some simple math, the code quickly shows the expected behavior: Multi-thread variant gets faster, if the computation is split among multiple threads, thus using multiple cores to get the result.

Comment: You're including thread creation and deletion in your measurement.

Comment: Your benchmarking loop has no observable effect. It could be optimized to a noop by the compiler. `lambda_fkt` could turn into `(){}`. Edit : This could be why you get better results with simpler benchmarking functions.

Comment: And in addition to the two comments above, never use linked lists.

Comment: The memory allocations required by the lists are typically not thread safe, resulting in one thread waiting for access to them.

Comment: All your operations are essentially applications of `new` and `delete` with some trivial wrapping. So you measure just these two functions. Depending on hardware, memory management is not improved at all when multithreading is involved. And certainly OS needs some sort of internal synchronisation routine to ensure that `new`/`delete` operations do not cause any data races.